# computing value of binary string

Tags: number-theory

How do we  compute the value of binary string S[0..9] modulo 3 efficiently if we know the corresponding value for S[0..4] and S[5..9] ?Let us say we have a binary string s 1010001010 of length 10 then how does the answer below satisfy this.

let value of S[0..4] be x and S[5..9] be y. Then value of S[0..9] will be x*(2^5)+y.

can anyone explain this solution more clearly and with proof.
I tried to work on a binary string but i could not prove it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a $10$-bit string, $b_0b_1\ldots b_9$. This represents the number

$$2^9b_0+2^8b_1+2^7b_2+2^6b_3+2^5b_4+2^4b_5+2^3b_6+2^2b_7+2^1b_8+2^0b_9\;.$$

This number is the sum of the numbers

$$z=2^9b_0+2^8b_1+2^7b_2+2^6b_3+2^5b_4$$

and

$$y=2^4b_5+2^3b_6+2^2b_7+2^1b_8+2^0b_9\;.$$

Now $y$ is simply the number represented by the $5$-bit string $b_5b_6b_7b_8b_9$; that’s your $S[5..9]$. For $z$ we have to do a little arithmetic: factoring out $2^5$, we find that

$$\begin{align*}
z&=2^9b_0+2^8b_1+2^7b_2+2^6b_3+2^5b_4\\
&=2^5(2^4b_0+2^3b_1+2^3b_2+2^1b_3+2^0b_4)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$x=2^4b_0+2^3b_1+2^3b_2+2^1b_3+2^0b_4$$

is by definition the number represented by the $5$-bit string $b_0b_1b_2b_3b_4$, your $S[0..4]$. Thus, the number represented by $b_0b_1\ldots b_9$ is $z+y=2^5x+y$.

In the specific case of the string $1010001010$, the number represented is

$$2^9+2^7+2^3+2^1=650\;.$$

The number represented by $10100$, the first five bits, is

$$2^4+2^2=20\;,$$

the number represented by $01010$, the second five bits, is

$$2^3+2^1=10\;,$$

and

$$2^5\cdot20+10=32\cdot20+10=640+10=650\;,$$

just as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by $2^n$ shifts the binary number to the left $n$ bits, i.e., adds $n$ zeros to the right. So, what happens is you just multiply $x$ by $2$ to the power of $n$ where $n$ is the length of $y$, then you add the resulting to $y$ it self.

To help you understand, try to multiply $1$ by $2$, $4$, $8$, etc. and then convert to binary, and count the number of zeros on the right.

Comment: can your explain your answer considering one string of 0 and 1 and proving it.